# How to solve Certificate Error in Fiddler

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, fiddler

When I tried connect to google.com from I got this Certificate Error:

`Session #3: The server (152.199.19.161) presented a certificate that did not validate, because it was issued to a different host.
 
    SANs: *.vo.msecnd.net, *.adn.azureedge.net, *.ads2.msads.net, *.aspnetcdn.com, *.azurecomcdn.net, *.azureedge.net, *.azureedge-test.net, *.cdn.skype.com, *.cdn.skype.net, *.cmsresources.windowsphone.com, *.cmsresources.windowsphone-int.com, *.dev.skype.com, *.fms.azureedge.net, *.microsoft-sbs-domains.com, *.secure.skypeassets.com, *.secure.skypeassets.net, *.wac.azureedge.net, *.wpc.azureedge.net, *.ec.azureedge.net, *.wpc.ec.azureedge.net, *.wac.ec.azureedge.net, *.adn.ec.azureedge.net, *.fms.ec.azureedge.net, ajax.microsoft.com, cdnads.msads.net, cdn-resources.windowsphone.com, cdn-resources-beta.windowsphone.com, ecnads1.msn.com, iecvlist.microsoft.com, images-cms-pn.windowsphone-int.com, images-cms-tst.windowsphone-int.com, lumiahelptipscdn.microsoft.com, lumiahelptipscdnqa.microsoft.com, lumiahelptipsmscdn.microsoft.com, lumiahelptipsmscdnqa.microsoft.com, montage.msn.com, mscrl.microsoft.com, r20swj13mr.microsoft.com, *.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net, *.origin.mediaservices.windows.net, download.sysinternals.com, amp.azure.net, rt.ms-studiosmedia.com, gtm.ms-studiosmedia.com, *.aisvc.visualstudio.com, *.cdn.powerbi.com, dist.asp.net, embed.powerbi.com, msitembed.powerbi.com, dxtembed.powerbi.com, *.cdn.powerappscdn.net, downloads.subscriptionsint.tfsallin.net, download.my.visualstudio.com, cdn.vsassets.io, cdnppe.vsassets.io, stream.microsoft.com, datafactory.azure.com, *.cortanaanalytics.com, do.skype.com, software-download.office.microsoft.com, software-download.microsoft.com, prss.centralvalidation.com, *.gallerycdn.vsassets.io, *.gallerycdnppe.vsassets.io, global.asazure.windows.net, download.learningdownloadcenter.microsoft.com, www.videobreakdown.com, www.breakdown.me, *.gallerycdntest.vsassets.io, agavecdn.o365weve-dev.com, agavecdn.o365weve-ppe.com, agavecdn.o365weve.com, download.visualstudio.com, *.Applicationinsights.net, *.Applicationinsights.io, *.Applicationinsights.microsoft.com, *.sfbassets.com, *.sfbassets.net, download.mono-project.com, *.streaming.media-test.windows-int.net, *.origin.mediaservices.windows-int.net, *.mp.microsoft.com, download.visualstudio.microsoft.com, software-download.coem.microsoft.com, cdn.wallet.microsoft-ppe.com, cdn.wallet.microsoft.com, vi.microsoft.com, *.nuget.org, *.nugettest.org, cdn.botframework.com, *.streaming.media.azure.net, *.streaming.media.azure-test.net, natick.research.microsoft.com, quotecenter.microsoft.com, quotecenter-ppe.microsoft.com, cdn.cloudappsecurity.com, *.yammer.com, *.videoindexer.ai, .api.videoindexer.ai SUBJECT: CN=.vo.msecnd.net`

I don't know why because I added Trust Root Certificate.